Entrar a servidor realizado en windows Server de forma remota
En mi empresa tienen un servidor realizado con Windows Server y tienen una carpeta compartida donde cada uno entra y ve sus archivos. Tambien se conectaba con OpenVPN para acceder de forma remota, luego movieron el servidor de oficina y ahora solo unos pocos pueden conectarse de forma remota, los demás solo nos podemos conectar desde la oficina conectados a la misma red del servidor. Entré al servidor y no tiene instalado openvpn pero los que entran de forma remota si usan openVPN GUI, alguna sugerencia de que puede ser?
